# Is there a cts:value-match equivalent in the Java API

Tags: marklogic, java

I am not finding a way to pass a match pattern in Java when doing a [`QueryManager.values()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/QueryManager.html#values-com.marklogic.client.query.ValuesDefinition-T-) call.

Is there an equivalent MarkLogic Java API method for [`cts:value-match()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-match)?

Answer (score 0):

No, the Java API doesn't provide a client interface for `cts:value-match()`.

You could create a Data Service that encapsulates the call to `cts:value-match()`:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/DataServices

Other approaches for executing scripts on the MarkLogic enode include resource service extensions and invoke:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices

Hoping that helps,